# Как задать стиль для кнопки с отображением дат, xaml эллемента "DatePicker"?

Tags: c#, wpf, style, datepicker

Как задать глобальный стиль в App.xaml для всех кнопок с отображением месяца (выделено красным) элемента DatePicker?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дело в том, что у меня в данном файле для всех кнопок прописана высота 22 пикселя и из за этого поле с отображением дат наполовину срезано как на картинке.

```
<!--Задаем высоту кнопок-->
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
</Style>
```

Мне нужно что бы для всех календарей задавался аналогичным образом стиль либо отменяющий стиль для кнопок, либо задающий высоту к примеру в 30 пикселей. Подскажите как это прописать, не совсем пойму как именно для вложенного элемента в класс DatePicker задать стиль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно переопределить стиль кнопок для DatePicker.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <!-- Reset the Button style inside the DatePicker to default values -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас получилось.